# How to change sepator in zotero BetterBibTex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, zotero, better-bibtex

Zotero extension BetterBibTex  use the following citekey format on its configuration

```
shorttitle(3,3) + auth + year
```

the format of citekey is separated by lower camelCase

```
titleAuthorYear
```

How can I change this configuration lowerCamelCase to use undescores as separators?

```
title_author_year
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't use Better BibTeX, but https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/citing/ suggests something like `auth.lower + '_' + shorttitle(3,0) + '_' + year` might do it.

Comment: It works, thanks `shorttitle(3,3).lower.condense(_) + '_' + auth.lower.condense(_) + '_' +  year`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The citation key generator is customisable as documented in https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/citing/.

Literal stuff like `_` can be added in quotation marks, so you might want to try

```
shorttitle(3,0) + '_' + auth.lower + '_' + year
```